# Send message to Urban airship using PHP

Tags: php, iphone, ios

I am iphone developer and i am working on application, in which i need to send notification to devices in which my application is installed. I done this with the help of Urban airship, now my requirement is to send message from CMS (PHP code) to urban airship(in which my application is registered) and that message will automatically send to my device as notification send earlier from urban airship. Some one guide me that how can i achieve this, or advise me any healthy way to achieve this target

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Urban Airship's API documentation can be found [here](http://urbanairship.com/docs/push.html). They also have [an article](https://support.urbanairship.com/entries/70144047-Simple-PHP-API-v3-examples) describing a simple use of the API, and an open-source [PHP library](https://github.com/urbanairship/php-library2).

Comment: https://support.urbanairship.com/customer/portal/articles/91072-simple-push-using-php-amp-the-api
this page is not existing 
it is giving me 404 error

Comment: https://github.com/urbanairship/php-library

it is also missing it is also 404 error

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
 define('APPKEY','XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'); // Your App Key
 define('PUSHSECRET', 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'); // Your Master Secret
 define('PUSHURL', 'https://go.urbanairship.com/api/push/');

 $contents = array();
 $contents['badge'] = "+1";
 $contents['alert'] = "PHP script test";
 $contents['sound'] = "cat.caf";
 $notification = array();
 $notification['ios'] = $contents;
 $platform = array();
 array_push($platform, "ios");

 $push = array("audience"=>"all", "notification"=>$notification, "device_types"=>$platform);

 $json = json_encode($push);

 $session = curl_init(PUSHURL);
 curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_USERPWD, APPKEY . ':' . PUSHSECRET);
 curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_POST, True);
 curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $json);
 curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_HEADER, False);
 curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, True);
 curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type:application/json', 'Accept: application/vnd.urbanairship+json; version=3;'));
 $content = curl_exec($session);
 echo $content; // just for testing what was sent

 // Check if any error occured
 $response = curl_getinfo($session);
 if($response['http_code'] != 202) {
     echo "Got negative response from server, http code: ".
     $response['http_code'] . "\n";
 } else {

     echo "Wow, it worked!\n";
 }

 curl_close($session);
?>
```

Comment: This is fantastic for me, but how do you specify a single device in place of "all"?

Comment: Just set audience from "all" to "{device id of your device}", in this example platform "ios" is used.

Comment: Thanks but that does not seem to work for me. My code is identical (except the keys, etc.) but it I get an http error 400 back instead of sending the notification. It works with "all". I used the format "audience"=>"DEVICEID". IS that correct?

Comment: Where did you defined your device id?

Comment: Please try "audience" : {"device_token" : "998BAD77A8347EFE7920F..............85D526AE42C598A629A73B9"}

Comment: I have tried that, and sadly, no luck. I am entering my device ID exactly as Urban Airship has it, and exactly like you have in your example above.